# Make textarea with setted height grow when new line is added

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, textarea

I have a `textarea` with a fix `height` of `70px`. When I press enter for a new line multiple times I would like to let the `height` of the `textarea` grow. At the moment, after the 6th line a scrollbar appears. This makes sense, because of the fix `height` of `70px`. But is there a way to solve this?

```css
textarea {
  min-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Hello World! Click "enter" for more lines...</textarea>
```

Comment: Min-height instead of height?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Forgott to write, I tried min-height, but didn't work (see updated snippet).

Comment: I think you will need javascript and control the length/amount of enters of the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can handle this with a simple javascript function, take a look at the snippet:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('txtArea');

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
             
function autosize(){
  var el = this;  
    setTimeout(function(){
      el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
      el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
    },0);
  
}
```

```css
textarea {
  min-height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtArea">Hello World! Click "enter" for more lines </textarea>
```

ALSO, if you want to, you can add a max height, here is the snippet:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('txtArea');

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
             
function autosize(){
  var el = this;
  el.style.cssText = 'overflow: hidden !important';
  
  if (el.scrollHeight > 120){
      el.style.cssText = 'overflow: scroll !important';
      el.style.cssText = 'height: 120px';
      textarea.removeEventListener('keydown', autosize);
  }else{
    setTimeout(function(){
      el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
      el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
    },0);
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  min-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtArea">Hello World! Click "enter" for more lines </textarea>
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way to solve it for textarea. I made an example with pure css but without textarea: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/EoLJKz Just use contenteditable elements, then it works also. Notice: If you take this solution, you can't set the property `resize` like you can do it with textareas. You will have to write JS for such a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use only `css` you can also create your element like this:

```js
function contentTransfer(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerHTML;
}
```

```css
.custom_textArea{
  min-height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid lightGray;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  outline: none;
}

.custom_textArea:focus{
  border: 1px solid darkGray;
}
```

```html
<p id="myTextArea" class="custom_textArea" contenteditable="true">my text</p>
<button onclick="contentTransfer()">get content</button>
<p class="container"></p>
```

Comment: and if you want to use it with a form that html itself submit it you can use a hidden `input` or `textarea` and `<button onclick='document.getElementById("your input ID or text area ID").value= document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerHTML; document.getElementById("your form ID").submit()'>submit</button>` as your submit button.